# In Android, why does a webpage display correctly on Google Chrome and not in a WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

My webpage works fine on Google Chrome on my Android phone, but it does not display well when I load it inside a WebView.

My WebView settings as follows:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: When you say it "does not display well" what do you mean?

Comment: I have a side-menu, when I try to open the page becomes white and nothing is displayed in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this before the settings but after you put in the URL

```
nameOfWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
nameOfWebView.buildDrawingCache();

webview.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Comment: Same problem. I did as you told 'before the settings but after you put in the URL'

`webview.loadUrl(CORRESPONDENCE_URL);

        webview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        webview.buildDrawingCache();

        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);`

Comment: And the web page itself is coming back blank or this side menu is blank?

Comment: Once I try to display the menu, the whole view turns to white.

This problem does not happen with Google Chrome on the same phone.

Comment: you can try setting the layerType of the webview. If that doesn't help. Hopefully someone else has some better ideas. Show your code might help others give you a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for your concern :)